# Without _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, whether LeanFT will work or not?

Tags: java-8, qtp, hp-uft, microfocus, leanft

My application under testing will work only in Java8 and doesn't need _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variables. So, without these environment variables, whether LeanFT14.53 will work or not? If yes let me know how to perform the same?

Because of these environment variables am unbale to launch application under testing and its throwing exception like "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mercury/..../hooks/interfaces/EventListenerListHookQTJA".

Note: I have installed JDK 1.8_172, apache maven 3.6.3, automation scripts are written in java and using Intellij IDEA as IDE.